# wxPython moving widgets

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm a very beginner of wxPython. Now I'm trying to make a static text moveable by using timer(), but the question is that when the later one appears, the former one just doesn't hide.
So I'm thinking in these ways:
(1) Is that because I'm using static text? Maybe it could be "moveable" while I'm using some other widgets?
(2) When I wanna use "hide" or "destroy" at first, it comes out "not defined".

Any helpful suggestion will be great, and below is my code(python version: 2.6):

```
#!/user/bin/python

import wx

pos_st = [[10,50],[40,50],[70,50],[100,50]]
i = -1

class Frame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id,
                          'Move widget',
                          size = (200,150),
                          style=wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.RESIZE_BORDER 
    | wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION |  wx.CLOSE_BOX)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.widgetPanel=wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.widgetPanel.SetBackgroundColour('white')

        # Buttons for play the simulation
        playButton = wx.Button(self.widgetPanel, -1, "Play", pos=(10,10), size=(30,30))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.play, playButton)
        playButton.SetDefault()

    def play(self, event):
        self.timer = wx.CallLater(1000, self.run_st)

    def run_st(self):
        global i
        i = (i+1)%4
        self.timer.Restart(1000)
        self.sT = wx.StaticText(self.widgetPanel, -1, '1',
                              pos=pos_st[i], size=(20,20))
        self.sT.SetBackgroundColour('grey')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = Frame(parent=None,id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the static part of StaticText actually has nothing to do with movement... or even mutability, but rather from a users perspective it is Static (ie they cannot alter it)

```
def run_st(self):
    global i
    i = (i+1)%4
    self.timer.Restart(1000)
    if not hasattr(self,"sT"):
        self.sT = wx.StaticText(self.widgetPanel, -1, '1', size=(20,20))
        self.sT.SetBackgroundColour('grey')
    self.sT.SetPosition(pos_st[i])
```

its because you are not changing the existing text position you are creating a new text each time ... this way you will just move the existing one ... although really you should use an actual timer

```
def initUI(self):

    self.widgetPanel=wx.Panel(self, -1)
    self.widgetPanel.SetBackgroundColour('white')

    # Buttons for play the simulation
    playButton = wx.Button(self.widgetPanel, -1, "Play", pos=(10,10), size=(30,30))

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.play, playButton)
    playButton.SetDefault()
    self.sT = wx.StaticText(self,-1,"",size=(20,20))
    self.timer = wx.Timer()
    self.timer.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER,self.run_st)
def play(self, event):
    self.timer.Start(1000)

def run_st(self,timerEvent):
    global i
    i = (i+1)%4
    self.sT.SetLabel("1")
    self.sT.SetPosition(pos_st[i])
```

Comment: Many thanks for your quick reply! While now the program shows:  File "que_simplify.py", line 32, in play
    self.timer.start()
AttributeError: 'Timer' object has no attribute 'start'

Comment: ehh try `.Start` instead I always get those mixed up (because python thread is `.start`)

Comment: And may I ask what can I use if I want a movable widget instead of static text?

Comment: you can move static text fine .... Im not sure what you mean by moveable? you mean like drag-drop? by the user (also note that i forgot the timer speed (which is an argument to `Start`

Comment: Brilliant! Now it works perfectly! And it's enough for the "movable" in my mind, thx!